# Custom UINavigationBar not work

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

how to create uinavigationbar as image in iOS , 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/253QR.png

I tried

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navi.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: First of all, I really don't know how you can implement that big sized navigation bar.

Second is, are you using standalone UINavigationBar or UINavigationController's UINavigationBar? If second, I changed it's backgroundImage too many times. I can share my code.

Comment: I'm using  UINavigationController's UINavigationBar ,
how can I overlay other views in my UIViewController.

Comment: All the customization need to be applied in parent view controller, before pushing target view controller. Kindly check...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The problem is, any controller cannot change the UINavigationBar of a UINavigationController directly. It must be changed by UINavigationController. I recommend to create a custom UINavigationController.

Assume that the name of the custom UINavigationController's name is NavController:

```
@interface NavController ()

@end

@implementation NavController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navi.png"];
   [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   [self.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];//you can change this
   self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];// you can change this too
}

@end
```

I was setting StoryBoard's UINavigationController's class to NavController. This is the easiest way to change all the UINavigationBars' background in any controllers. If you want to change any specific controller's background use this  (too long not using. may be wrong but something like this):

```
 UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navi.png"];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage: navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

OK I just looked into my old codes. It must be correct.